# Trouble Dereferencing a double pointer to struct

Tags: c, dereference

I can't seem to be able to read the data being pointed to by the double pointer. It's for an assignment for i must use the double pointer.

Getting below error:

```
Error: Access violation reading location.
```

Here is the code:

```
struct Fraction {

        int num, denom;<br>
};
struct PolyTerm {

        struct Fraction coeff;
        int exponent;v
};
struct PolyNode {

    struct PolyTerm** dataPtr;
    struct PolyNode* next;
};

void printPolyTerm(struct PolyTerm** argTerm) { // this function works fine><br>

        printFraction(&(argTerm->coeff));       //also works fine
        printf(" X^%d", argTerm->expo);
        return;
}
void printPolyNode(const PolyNode* node) {  //NOT WORKING<br>

        struct PolyTermPS** ppTerm = node->dataPtr;
        struct PolyTermPS* pTerm = *ppTerm;
        printPolyTerm(pTerm);
        return;
}
```

Comment: Could the assignment possibly have meant `double*`?

Comment: So, `const PolicyNode*`? I don't supposed there is a typedef for that.  And it being `const`? Considering you're assigning one of its members to a non-const `ppTerm`? And no `printFraction()` anywhere to be seen. Hmm. You'll understand if we take the "works fine" commentary at face-value. Ex: `printf(" X^%d", argTerm->expo)` ? `argTerm` is a pointer-to-pointer. `(*argTerm)->expo` probably has more teeth (and *almost* compiles, except the member isn't called `expo`, is called `exponent`). In short. Got something that *compiles* ??

Answer (score 0):

Function `void printPolyTerm(struct PolyTerm** argTerm)` accepts a double pointer, so, your call from `void printPolyNode(const PolyNode* node)` must be changed:

```
void printPolyNode(const PolyNode* node) {  //NOT WORKING<br>

    struct PolyTermPS** ppTerm = node->dataPtr;
    struct PolyTermPS* pTerm = *ppTerm;
    printPolyTerm(pTerm);
    return;
}
```

must be

```
void printPolyNode(const PolyNode* node) {  //NOT WORKING<br>

    struct PolyTerm** ppTerm = node->dataPtr;
    struct PolyTerm* pTerm = *ppTerm;
    printPolyTerm(&pTerm);
    return;
}
```

Now, inside `void printPolyTerm(struct PolyTerm** argTerm)` function you must dereference a double pointer, I mean:

- `argTerm` is a pointer to a `struct PolyTerm` pointer.
- `*argTerm` is a pointer to `struct PolyTerm`

So, you must replace

```
void printPolyTerm(struct PolyTerm** argTerm) { // this function works fine><br>

    printFraction(&(argTerm->coeff));       //also works fine
    printf(" X^%d", argTerm->expo);
    return;
}
```

by

```
void printPolyTerm(struct PolyTerm** argTerm) { // this function works fine><br>

    printFraction(&((*argTerm)->coeff));       //also works fine
    printf(" X^%d", (*argTerm)->exponent);
    return;
}
```

Another situation works only because you are so lucky.